# Using iTextSharp and detecting italic words

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using the C# library iTextSharp to extract the text from a pdf document. The pdf contains a header in italics, and i would like to detect this word and grab the text from beneath it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-check-if-font-bold You may not be able to detect if the font is italic (or bold, or bold and italic). I'm tempted to close this question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Actually the article you refer to indicates that there is no way to recognize *bold* text. The font flag table, though, which you quote there, clearly has an entry "italic". Thus, not a duplicate in my eyes.

Comment: sgov090: But that does not make detecting italic words easier in general because indicators like those flags often are not properly set by PDF creating software. If your PDFs are from a single PDF creating software, though, you might have more luck. You'd have to share representative sample files, though, to allow us recognize how one might be able to spot a pattern that allows recognition of italic fonts.